# Publishing web application to Azure via command line error

Tags: azure, msbuild

I'm trying to publish my web application to Azure existing web application with MSBuild from command line:

`.\MSBuild.exe $solutionPath /T:$project /T:Rebuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy /p:PublishProfile=$publishProfilePath /p:password=$password /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true`

and I'm getting the following error:

`msdeploy error ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC: Web deployment task fail
ed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("appName.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond.`

But when I deploy the same application with same publishing profile from Visual Studio 15 it work fine. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem was with our IT using a proxy server.
The solution is to add

`<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>`

to the "MSBuild.exe.config" file